# Refresh view display when underlying data changes

Tags: android

I have seen this question answered a few times in which it is suggested to use the method notifyDataSetChanged() from BaseAdapter.

Is there a way to refresh when your application does not use any adapters? I have a simple application where I use a few activities with preferences, and relative layouts with text views and buttons. At the moment I do not use any of the adapters like SimpleAdapter or ArrayAdapter or CursorAdapter. It seems like in my case I have to create one of them just to get to use notifyDataSetChanged()? There is no easier way for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like (I may be mistaken, but it really looks like) you don't catch the purpose of those classes - `SimpleAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`. They are expected to work with `ListView` inside of an `Activity` (or even better - inside of a `ListActivity`). If you don't use `ListView` then those adapers are most likely useless for you.

I assume you have your data persisted in some way (`SharedPreferences` or file). So if you start any of your Activities, then it just reads the data to populate the views. In this case nothing extra is needed. In case if you need to reload data for a currently visible Activity, then just reread the data from persistent storage and repopulate the views.

Comment: I do use SharedPreferences. I have an activity displaying a screen. I set an alarm, it goes off, a service starts, and the service starts an alarm dialog in a new activity on top of the screen. The user clicks ok to make the dialog disappear. When it disappears, I am back at the original screen but the original screen stays untouched, no changes. I just need to change a string on the original screen because of what the user did. I guess I should just create the whole screen again?

Comment: @MLW - Ok, here is an approach - in the `Activity` you'd like to refresh its views (the original screen) you should reread data from SharedPreferences and repopulate the views in `Activity.onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is changing and you need to refresh your view, how is the data actually changing? Is it in a separate thread or, do you just want something to happen periodically (polling an RSS feed, or something)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a radio group, and each radio button had a label. When the screen rotated, I used a different layout with a radio group & radio buttons with the same IDs. I was calling setContentView() in onCreate(): and after rotation, the “old” labels would show up on the new layout (bizarre). When I moved setContentView() to onResume, everything seems to update ok. Thanks to Arhimed for his answer above.